# Windows Forms with LocalService Database connection error

Tags: c#, datasource

I've created an application that users SQL LOCAL SERVICE DB of Visual Studio.
So when I'm working from my PC the connection with service database works, but when I try deploy a release and share with another PC the release folder and try to open any tab of application I'm getting this SQL error of connection.

[image: SQL CONNECTION ERROR]
[image: Connection String]

This is code of the datasource path of connection that I'm using.

```
public LocalDBClass() //Conexao com Local DB
{
    try
    {
        stringConn = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\Database\\CMEDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
        MessageBox.Show(stringConn,"Conexao", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
      
        connDB = new SqlConnection(stringConn);
        connDB.Open();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
```

I need to copy or install something in the client PC to this app works with localservice DB provided by Visual Studio

Comment: connect to the server with ssms and see how the name of the server really is

Comment: Yes, if you're using the SQL Server Express LocalDB in your application, then this also needs to be installed on any other PC where you want to run your application on.

Comment: No, Im using the VisualStudiao SQL Service db

Comment: That connection string you're using is for **SQL Server Express LocalDB** ....

Answer (score 0):

To fix the issue, I need to instal localdb sql express on client PC and resolved.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).